# angular2 External link redirect by clicking on the items loaded

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to create an application using Ionic2 angular2. Been using it for quite sometime now. I want to open google page search for the item that is loaded dynamically in the view

for creating the view I have the following code.

```
this.initializeItems();
  }
  initializeItems() {
    this.items=[

    'Tennis',
    'cricket',
    'Football',
    'Table tennis',
    'Badminton',
  ];
  }
```

So when I click each Item it should open the google search page as

Can someone tell me how to do this.

Comment: use a tag and then try to give www.google.com in the href thats it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <a [href]="'https://www.google.com/search?q='+item">Search {{item}}</a>
</div>
```

OR

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <a [attr.href]="'https://www.google.com/search?q='+item">Search {{item}}</a>
</div>
```

Not sure if you'll need the `attr` but I do think so.

Comment: Thank you very much.I am almost there